# Test new nameservers before switching over DNS host

Tags: macos, dns, nameserver

Switching the host for our name servers. DNS records are set up on both the old nameservers and the new ones. I’d like to test the new ones before switching over our SOA and wondering what are the best ways to test them before committing to them?

My [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) skills are weak. Ideally I would force my local machine to use the new nameserver for our domain so I can check HTTP and HTTPS services are working correctly.

Comment: specifically that our website won't go down. `example.com` should redirect to `www.example.com` for both `http` & `https`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. We're changing DNS hosting providers. DNS records are set up on both the old nameservers and the new ones. I'd like to test the new ones before switching over our SOA and wondering what the best ways to test are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Switching the host for our name servers. DNS records are set up on
>   both the old nameservers and the new ones. I’d like to test the new
>   ones before switching over our SOA and wondering what are the best
>   ways to test them before committing to them?

In general, if they look correct and have the same entries in both places, just a switch in SOA will get you going without too much worry. Of course do not delete or get rid if the old DNS entries until at least 24 hours after the switch is made. While 98% of the servers in the world will accept the change pretty much immediately, you gotta remember there are all kinds of crappy DNS servers out there that don’t respect TTLs and better wait and then ditch when the dust settles than just rush to get rid of it and end up with failed lookups.

> My [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) skills are weak. Ideally I would force my local machine
>   to use the new nameserver for our domain so I can check HTTP and HTTPS
>   services are working correctly.

This simplest thing you can do if both DNS servers are set with your data is to use `dig` to query a specific DNS server and not just your systems local default.

For example, this query would do a query for the authoritative `NS` (namservers) for a hostname on the OpenDNS servers:

```
dig @208.67.222.222 NS example.com
dig @208.67.222.220 NS example.com
```

And this would provide you with any records for that domain name on that DNS server; note only the `NS` option is replace by `ANY`:

```
dig @208.67.222.222 ANY example.com
dig @208.67.222.220 ANY example.com
```

Similarly, this would do the same `NS` query but using Google’s DNS servers:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 NS example.com
dig @8.8.4.4 NS example.com
```

And again this would provide you with any records for that domain name on that other DNS server:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 ANY example.com
dig @8.8.4.4 ANY example.com
```

You could do that with a few top tier DNS servers to make sure they are respecting the DNS change when it happens.

In general, SOA TTL times are about 900 seconds (aka: 15 minutes), so if you feel unsure about this my advice would be to just set the SOA TTL on the old DNS server to 300 (aka: 5 minutes) and then wait two hours or so and then do the switch. The 5 minute change gives you quick enough turn around so if something unpleasant happens you can quickly switch back to the old DNS servers without too much worry.

In general, this kind of stuff is a dance of requests and TTLs so patience in the flow is mandatory. But like I said, if all of the entries are correct in both setups you should be fine; the SOA TTL of 300 seconds is just a simple, harmless suggestion.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!  Do you know, offhand, how to use dig to pull all the records from both my old & new nameservers so I can compare the two?

Comment: n/m I found: `dig @new.nameserver mydomain.com any`

Comment: This is a great answer. I would just add that if you are REALLY worried, you could always boot a simple VM and point it explicitly to the new DNS server and use it for a bit to make sure resolutions happen as expected.